# How to display pdf file in webpage using iframe with spring Framework?

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to display pdf file in webpage using iframe with spring framework. Instead of download options i have to show pdf file in my webpage. Pls anyone can help me.

Thanks in advance..

My java code:

```
Employee employee = employeeManager.getObjectOrNull(
            Employee .class, id);
    File file = new File(dir,
            employee .getFileName());
    org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file,
            employee .getfile());

    if (employee != null) {
        ControllerUtils.openFile(dir,
                response, employee.getFileName());
        String contentType = Utils.getContentType(employee 
                .getFileName());
        response.setContentType(contentType);
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=5");
```

Comment: I got solutions. I did using embed tag. My HTML code:<embed width="900px" height="500px" name="plugin" src="/employee/downloadPayslip" type="application/pdf">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got the solution. I used `embed` tag. My HTML code:

```
<embed width="900px" height="500px" name="plugin" src="/content/downloadPdf" type="application/pdf">
```

My java code

```
        response.setContentType("application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "private, max-age=5");

        response.setHeader("Pragma", "");
        if (file.length>0) {
            response.setContentLength(file.length);
        }
        ServletOutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(file);
        try {
            int b;
            while ((b = is.read()) != -1) {
                ouputStream.write(b);
            }
        } finally {
            ouputStream.flush();
            ouputStream.close();
            is.close();
        }
```

Comment: How do you mapped src url ?

Comment: Do you any github project for this?